# How to fix AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I'm trying to build an ai based chatbot based on a tutorial, they're using python 3.5 and tensorflow 1.0.0.

I have crossed checked everything, my virtual environment is running from inside the anaconda explorer. I even ran it from the terminal and activated it. I'm importing everything correctly and all. Although I installed tensorflow 1.0.0 using anaconda terminal with virtual env activated, when I look it up in anacoda it says 1.1.0. I don't know if there is major difference in there or not, so that thing i'm not sure about.
Upon running this code
**tf.reset_default_graph()
session = tf.InteractiveSession()**
Instead of spyder successfully running, it shows an error that AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph'.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import re
import time 
### Phase 1: Data Preprocessing ###

# Importing the dataset
lines = open('movie_lines.txt', encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore').read().split('\n')
conversations = open('movie_conversations.txt', encoding = 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore').read().split('\n')

# Creating a dictionary that maps each line with its id
id_to_line = {}
for line in lines:
    _line = line.split(' +++$+++ ')
    if len(_line) == 5:
        id_to_line[_line[0]] = _line[4]

# Creating a list of conversations
conversations_ids = []
for conversation in conversations[:-1]:
    _conversation = conversation.split(' +++$+++ ')[-1][1:-1].replace("'", "").replace(" ", "")
    conversations_ids.append(_conversation.split(','))

# Getting questions and answers seperately
questions= []
answers = []
for conversation in conversations_ids:
    for i in range(len(conversation) - 1):
        questions.append(id_to_line[conversation[i]])
        answers.append(id_to_line[conversation[i]])

# Cleaning Texts by removing apostrophes and putting everything in lowercase
def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am", text)
    text = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "what is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"how's", "how is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", text)
    text = re.sub(r"n't", " not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"can't", "cannot", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", text)
    return text

# Cleaning Questions
clean_questions = []
for question in questions:
    clean_questions.append(clean_text(question))

# Cleaning Answers
clean_answers = []
for answer in answers:
    clean_answers.append(clean_text(answer))

# Filtering out the questions and answers that are too short or too long    
short_questions = []
short_answers = []
i = 0
for question in clean_questions:
    if 2 <= len(question.split()) <= 25:
        short_questions.append(question)
        short_answers.append(clean_answers[i])
    i += 1
clean_questions = []
clean_answers = []
i = 0
for answer in short_answers:
    if 2 <= len(answer.split()) <= 25:
        clean_answers.append(answer)
        clean_questions.append(short_questions[i])
    i += 1


# Creating a Dictionary to map each word to its number of occurences
word_to_count = {}
for question in clean_questions:
    for word in question.split():
        if word not in word_to_count:
            word_to_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_to_count[word] += 1

for answer in clean_answers:
    for word in answer.split():
        if word not in word_to_count:
            word_to_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_to_count[word] += 1

# Doing Tokenization & Filtering non-frequent words
threshold = 20
ques_words_to_int = {}
word_count = 0
for word, count in word_to_count.items():
    if count >= threshold:
        ques_words_to_int[word] = word_count
        word_count += 1

ans_words_to_int = {}
word_count = 0
for word, count in word_to_count.items():
    if count >= threshold:
        ans_words_to_int[word] = word_count
        word_count += 1 

# Adding last tokens to above two Dictionaries
tokens = ['<PAD>', '<EOS>', '<OUT>', '<SOS>']
for token in tokens:
    ques_words_to_int[token] = len(ques_words_to_int) + 1
for token in tokens:
    ans_words_to_int[token] = len(ans_words_to_int) + 1

# Creating Inverse Dictionary of ans_words_to_int
ans_ints_to_word = {w_i: w for w, w_i in ans_words_to_int.items()}

# Adding <EOS> to end of every answer for SEQ2SEQ Decoding
for i in range(len(clean_answers)):
    clean_answers[i] += ' <EOS>'

# Translating all ques & ans into int & replacing all words, filtered out by <OUT>
ques_into_int = []
for question in clean_questions:
    ints = []
    for word in question.split():
        if word not in ques_words_to_int:
            ints.append(ques_words_to_int['<OUT>'])
        else:
            ints.append(ques_words_to_int[word])
    ques_into_int.append(ints)

ans_into_int = []
for answer in clean_answers:
    ints = []
    for word in answer.split():
        if word not in ans_words_to_int:
            ints.append(ans_words_to_int['<OUT>'])
        else:
            ints.append(ans_words_to_int[word])
    ans_into_int.append(ints)

# Sorting ques & ans by length of questions
sorted_clean_questions = []
sorted_clean_answers = []
for length in range(1, 25):
    for i in enumerate(ques_into_int):
        if len(i[1]) == length:
            sorted_clean_questions.append(ques_into_int[i[0]])
            sorted_clean_answers.append(ans_into_int[i[0]])

### Phase 2: Building SEQ2SEQ Model ###

# Creating placeholders for inputs and targets
def model_inputs():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'Learning_rate')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'Keep_prob')
    return inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob

# Preprocessing the targets
def preprocess_targets(targets, word_to_int, batch_size):
    left_side = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], word_to_int['<SOS>'])
    right_side = tf.strided_slice(targets, [0,0], [batch_size, -1], [1,1])
    preprocessed_targets = tf.concat([left_side, right_side], 1)
    return preprocessed_targets

# Creating the Encoder RNN Layer
def encoder_rnn_layer(rnn_inputs, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length):
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
    _, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw = encoder_cell,
                                                       cell_bw = encoder_cell,
                                                       sequence_length = sequence_length,
                                                       inputs = rnn_inputs,
                                                       dtype = tf.float32)
    return encoder_state

# Decoding the Training Set
def decode_training_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embedded_input, sequence_length, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    training_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train(encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_train")
    decoder_output, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                              training_decoder_function,
                                                                                                              decoder_embedded_input,
                                                                                                              sequence_length,
                                                                                                              scope = decoding_scope)
    decoder_output_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(decoder_output, keep_prob)
    return output_function(decoder_output_dropout)

# Decoding the test/validation set
def decode_test_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embeddings_matrix, sos_id, eos_id, maximum_length, num_words, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    test_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference(output_function,
                                                                              encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                                              sos_id,
                                                                              eos_id,
                                                                              maximum_length,
                                                                              num_words,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_inf")
    test_predictions, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                                test_decoder_function,
                                                                                                                scope = decoding_scope)
    return test_predictions

# Creating the Decoder RNN
def decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input, decoder_embeddings_matrix, encoder_state, num_words, sequence_length, rnn_size, num_layers, word_to_int, keep_prob, batch_size):
    with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
        lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
        decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
        weights = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1)
        biases = tf.zeros_initializer()
        output_function = lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x,
                                                                      num_words,
                                                                      None,
                                                                      scope = decoding_scope,
                                                                      weights_initializer = weights,
                                                                      biases_initializer = biases)
        training_predictions = decode_training_set(encoder_state,
                                                   decoder_cell,
                                                   decoder_embedded_input,
                                                   sequence_length,
                                                   decoding_scope,
                                                   output_function,
                                                   keep_prob,
                                                   batch_size)
        decoding_scope.reuse_variables()
        test_predictions = decode_test_set(encoder_state,
                                           decoder_cell,
                                           decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                           word_to_int['<SOS>'],
                                           word_to_int['<EOS>'],
                                           sequence_length - 1,
                                           num_words,
                                           decoding_scope,
                                           output_function,
                                           keep_prob,
                                           batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions

# Building the SEQ2SEQ Model
def seq2seq_model(inputs, targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, answers_num_words, questions_num_words, encoder_embedding_size, decoder_embedding_size, rnn_size, num_layers, ques_words_to_int):
    encoder_embedded_input = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(inputs,
                                                              answers_num_words + 1,
                                                              encoder_embedding_size,
                                                              initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(0, 1))
    encoder_state = encoder_rnn_layer(encoder_embedded_input, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length)
    preprocessed_targets = preprocess_targets(targets, ques_words_to_int, batch_size)
    decoder_embeddings_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([questions_num_words + 1, decoder_embedding_size], 0, 1))
    decoder_embedded_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings_matrix, preprocessed_targets)
    training_predictions, test_predictions = decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input,
                                                         decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                         encoder_state,
                                                         questions_num_words,
                                                         sequence_length,
                                                         rnn_size,
                                                         num_layers,
                                                         ques_words_to_int,
                                                         keep_prob,
                                                         batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions  

### Phase 3: Training the SEQ2SEQ Model ###

# Setting the Hyperparameters
epochs = 100
batch_size = 32
rnn_size = 1024
num_layers = 3
encoding_embedding_size = 1024
decoding_embedding_size = 1024
learning_rate = 0.001
learning_rate_decay = 0.9
min_learning_rate = 0.0001
keep_probability = 0.5

# Defining a session
tf.reset_default_graph()
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

I fixed the issue by deactivating and reactivating the virtual env and then running the command "pip install --user tensorflow=1.0.0" and also `pip3 install --user tensorflow=1.0.0` and then that attribute error related to tf.reset_default_graph() session = tf.InteractiveSession() was solved

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example here? It seems like you've posted a lot of code but only talking about one problem in particular. If you narrow down your code to just demonstrate the issue, this will help people answer your question better.

Comment: I solved the issue. from next time, i'll try to post questions in a cleaner way, Sorry.
I fixed the issue by deactivating and reactivating the virtual env and then running the command "pip install --user tensorflow=1.0.0" and also "pip3 install --user tensorflow=1.0.0" and then that attribute error related to tf.reset_default_graph() session = tf.InteractiveSession() was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. from next time, I'll try to post questions in a cleaner way, Sorry. I fixed the issue by deactivating and reactivating the virtual env and then running the command `pip install --user tensorflow=1.0.0` and also `pip3 install --user tensorflow=1.0.0` and then that attribute error related to `tf.reset_default_graph() session = tf.InteractiveSession()` was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we don't have to uninstall Tensorflow 2. x and re-install 1. x to avoid this problem. Someone can avoid doing so by the following techniques.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Here we are disabling TF2 behavior and activating TF1 behavior.