# Multiple versions of Tensorflow causing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, knowledge-graph

Long story: I use an Amazon EC2 instance and was trying to use this package called Ampligraph, which uses TensorFlow(TF) internally. I installed it through PIP using this [installation guide](https://docs.ampligraph.org/en/1.1.0/install.html). I ran these below scripts to load a model to the system.

```
from ampligraph.utils import restore_model
model = restore_model(model_name_path = model_path)
```

It gives me `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'

I followed multiple StackOverFlow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272792/how-to-fix-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-reset-default-g) and understood that there's something wrong with the TF version I have.

When I run the below command to check TF version

```
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
```

This is what I get:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so.5. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3517] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:455: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:456: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:457: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:458: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:459: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
1.0.1
```

So, I understand that the version of TF is 1.0.1 (last line).

Again, I installed TF through pip:

```
sudo pip3 install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

It gets installed successfully. However, when I run the command to check TF version, it shows the same messages as above and the version is still 1.0.1

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the long post
Thanks!

Comment: First, check whether `pip3` matches the interpreter aliased to `python3` (run `pip3 --version` and check the interpreter version is 3.5). Second, you may have two versions of `tensorflow` installed simultaneously for the same interpreter - the global one (installed via `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`) and the user-only one (installed via `pip3 install tensorflow --user`, note no `sudo` used). To check that, run `pip3 list --user` and check whether `tensorflow` is listed. If yes, either uninstall the user-only one (`pip3 uninstall tensorflow --user`) or upgrade it.

Comment: Could you please add this as an answer. It worked well for me, would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether `pip3` matches the interpreter aliased to `python3`: run

```
$ pip3 --version
```

and check the interpreter version is 3.5. Example output:

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

If the version doesn't match, you have multiple versions of Python installed and `pip3` installs packages for the other Python version. Determine what command is aliased to `pip` for Python 3.5 (e.g. `pip3.5` or `python3.5 -m pip`) and reinstall `tensorflow` for Python 3.5 using the correct command.

Second, you may have two versions of `tensorflow` installed simultaneously for the same interpreter - the global one (installed via `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`) and the user-only one (installed via `pip3 install tensorflow --user`, note no `sudo` used). To check that, run:

```
$ pip3 list --user
```

and check whether `tensorflow` is listed. If yes, either uninstall the user-only one:

```
$ pip3 uninstall tensorflow --user
```

or upgrade it and uninstall the global one:

```
$ pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade --user
$ sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow -y
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this. I did the first step: pip3 --version and got a similar output. But, I had 2 versions of tensorflow for same user, both gpu and the cpu one. Removed gpu version and it started working.

Comment: Glad I could help!